# How can I match an IP address in Perl?

Tags: perl, ip-address

I have a local DNS script that I've inherited from a past employee that needs to compare some values to see if they match specific MX records and IP addresses.

The MX part I have down okay:

```
120 $doug = doug.local
139 if ($mx_record =~ /$doug/) {
140         print ("Mail on doug.\n");
141 }
142         else {
143                 print ("Not on doug.\n");
144 }
```

`$mx_record` is a line from an mx query that would look like this:

```
thomas.            302     IN      MX      10 doug.local.
```

Now I need to see if the A record matches.

The `$a_record` variable from the query looks like this.

```
thomas.            300     IN      A       10.0.0.47
```

How do I do a conditional statement to match an IP address?

I need to define the IP in a variable and then see if the `$a_record` variable contains that defined IP.

Comment: Are you only interested in IPv4 addresses that are expressed as a dotted quad?  Are IP addresses expressed as hex values also a possible input?

Comment: Only IPv4 addresses expressed as dotted quad.

Comment: Is this coming from a program like dig or are you parsing a file?

Comment: @Schwern: from dig, yup.

Comment: @scraft3613 Then don't bother parsing dig output.  Use Net::DNS to query information about a domain and get it back as neat objects.  No screen scraping required.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to match an IPv4 regex, use [Regexp::Common::net](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp::Common::net).

Rather than running a regex over the whole line, its safer to tokenize them and match individual parts as necessary.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

sub parse_record {
    my $line = shift;

    # special rules for parsing different types
    my %More4Type = (
        MX      => sub { return( priority => $_[0], provider => $_[1] ) },
        default => sub { return( provider => $_[0] ) }
    );

    my(%record, @more);
    (@record{qw(host uhh class type)}, @more) = split /\s+/, $line;
    my $more_func = $More4Type{$record{type}} || $More4Type{default};
    %record = (%record, $more_func->(@more));

    return \%record;
}

while(my $line = <DATA>) {
    print Dumper parse_record($line);
}

__END__
thomas.            302     IN      MX      10 doug.local.
thomas.            300     IN      A       10.0.0.47
google.com.     24103   IN  NS  ns2.google.com.
```

Now that you've parsed the line, its a simple matter of looking at `$record{type}` and `$record{provider}` or whatever you need.  For a little bit of effort this is far more flexible and less bug prone.

Though there's probably something on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) to do the parsing for you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a better way, but this will get you pretty close:

```
if($a_record =~ /((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})/) {
     warn "IP was: $1";
}

# IP was: 10.0.0.47
```

This matches `10.0.0.` then the final `47`.

Answer (score 1):

This will match a entry that looks like a ip address, but will also match 999.999.999.999.  Make sure to validate the matched address before using it.

```
if ($mx_record =~ /(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/) {...}
```

Comment: This is the right approach...as long as each part of the quad is validated to be in the 0-25 range.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if ($mx_record =~ /A\w+(<record_ip>(?:/[0-9]{1,3}.){4})/ {
   print $record_ip
}
```

This will check for A followed by whitespace, followed by a dotted quad.  The quad is saved in the variable $record_ip

Comment: Why are you restricting the pattern to digits that are 0-5?  How could that match a private in the 192.168.x.x space?

Comment: ... becuase I suddenly started thinking about old (non-CIDR netmasks...  will fix.

Comment: Why would you post code that you haven't tested?  You want \s+, not \w+.  You should quote the \., or it matches any character.  And the regex looks for addresses with a trailing dot.  The only reason this code might have worked is that the \n at the end of the line got parsed as part of the address.  Try instead:      if (/A\s+((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})/)

Answer (score 0):

```
my $a_record = 'thomas.            300     IN      A       10.0.0.47';
my $ip = '10.0.0.47';

if ($a_record =~ /\b(\Q$ip\E)$/) {
    print "Matches: $1\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the IP address might not be in its most compact decimal notation, I suggest you should use the `inet_aton()` function from the `Socket` module:

```
use Socket;

my $ip_to_match = inet_aton('10.0.0.47');
...
if (inet_aton($field) == $ip_to_match) {
    ...
}
```

NB: assumes that the DNS record has already been split down to its component parts